# Android stop-start AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask (AddressUpdaterTask) that gets a text from an AutoCompleteTextView, parses it and then shows a dropdown list of addresses just like when you type an address in google maps. Every time the user types a character a new AddressUpdaterTask is executed. My problem is that this is not efficient because when the user starts typing, if he types fast enough, a new AsyncTask is executed while the one before may have not finished executing.

So i have done this:

```
AddressUpdaterTask addressUpdaterTask = new AddressUpdaterTask();
```

Where addressUpdaterTask is global and when the user types a character i do this:

```
addressUpdaterTask.cancel(true);
addressUpdaterTask.execute();
```

So i can manipulate one instance of AddressUpdaterTask. But this way it doesn't work :(
How can i implement what i want?

Edit: Here is my code:

```
public class RegisterDoctor extends Activity {

        .
        .
        .

    private AutoCompleteTextView addressField;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private Filter filter;
    private List<SimpleAddress> simpleAddresses = new ArrayList<SimpleAddress>();
    private SimpleAddress currentAddress = null;
    AddressUpdaterTask addressUpdaterTask = new AddressUpdaterTask();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_doctor);

        .
        .
        .


        //AutoCompleteTextView Creation
        addressField = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
        addressField.setThreshold(ADDRESS_TRESHOLD);
        addressField.setHint("Οδός Αριθμός, Περιοχή");
        filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                Log.i("FILTER_ACTION", "Filter:" + constraint);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > ADDRESS_TRESHOLD) {
                    Log.i("FILTER_ACTION", "doing a search ..");
                    addressUpdaterTask.cancel(true);
                    addressUpdaterTask.execute();
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line) {
            public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
                return filter;
            }
        };
        addressField.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
        addressField.setOnItemClickListener(itemClicked);

        .
        .
        .

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClicked = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            currentAddress = simpleAddresses.get(pos);
            Log.i("ITEM_CLICKED", simpleAddresses.get(pos).getFormatted_address());
        }
    };

        .
        .
        .

    public class AddressUpdaterTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            //adapter.clear();
        }


        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                simpleAddresses = new JsonHelper().getAddresses(addressField.getText().toString());
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
            return null;
        }
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            int size = simpleAddresses.size();

            if (size > 0) {
                adapter.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    adapter.add(simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address());
                    Log.i("ADDRESS_ADDED", simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                addressField.showDropDown();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
        .
        .
        .
}
```

**Edit 2**: Here is the logcat from the moment the user types => 6 characters (the threshold i have put) and the AsyncTask can be executed:

```
10-11 18:56:59.795    1465-1494/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepi
10-11 18:57:02.695    1465-1494/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepis
10-11 18:57:02.695    1465-1494/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:06.544    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepist
10-11 18:57:06.544    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:06.555    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-11 18:57:09.004    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepisti
10-11 18:57:09.004    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:09.014    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-11 18:57:09.904    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepistim
10-11 18:57:09.904    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:09.914    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-11 18:57:10.194    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepistimi
10-11 18:57:10.194    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:10.194    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-11 18:57:11.865    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepistimio
10-11 18:57:11.865    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:11.954    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-11 18:57:12.196    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepistimiou
10-11 18:57:12.196    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:12.295    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-11 18:57:14.795      404-966/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.android.inputmethod.latin.dictionarypack
10-11 18:57:14.805      404-966/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/BinaryDictionaryGetter: Could not find a dictionary pack
10-11 18:57:14.815    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: Filter:panepistimiou
10-11 18:57:14.815    1465-1496/com.user.project I/FILTER_ACTION: doing a search ..
10-11 18:57:14.815    1465-1496/com.user.project W/Filter: An exception occured during performFiltering()!
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:578)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
        at com.user.project.RegisterDoctor$2.performFiltering(RegisterDoctor.java:104)
        at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: what exactly does the task do? network?

Comment: @jeffrey-blattman yes, i use google maps geocode api

Comment: what exactly does "doesn't work" mean? i'd expect that even if the task didn't cancel, it would still eventually update correctly. you'd end up with a queue of tasks for each char change.

Comment: The adapter i use is not updated. So no dropdown list. But when i simply do new AddressUpdaterTask().execute(); it works but it's laggy.

Comment: sounds like you need to take a broader look at this. the adapter should be updated regardless.

Answer (score 0):

When implementing an autocomplete, you typically introduce some delay so that the service is not called multiple times without getting a result back.

Try adding a variable (possibly static) that keeps track of when the user entered their first input, and only executing the search after a certain time period (500-750ms is fairly common) has elapsed.  This is a better UX, but doesn't solve your initial problem.

For your "double execution" problem, just put a conditional that is set to true when the request starts, and set to false when it finishes, and don't allow another request to start while the variable is set.

Something like this:

```
bool requestInProgress = false;

...

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    requestInProgress = true;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    int size = simpleAddresses.size();

    if (size > 0) {
        adapter.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            adapter.add(simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address());
            Log.i("ADDRESS_ADDED", simpleAddresses.get(i).getFormatted_address());
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        addressField.showDropDown();
    }
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    requestInProgress = false;
}
```

And above...

```
@Override
protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
    Log.i("FILTER_ACTION", "Filter:" + constraint);
    if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > ADDRESS_TRESHOLD 
           && !requestInProgress) {
        Log.i("FILTER_ACTION", "doing a search ..");
        addressUpdaterTask.cancel(true);
        addressUpdaterTask.execute();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: " just put a conditional that is set to true when the request starts, and set to false when it finishes" -- not necessary, because standard implementation of AsyncTask serializes all requests already.